# Функция которая выполняется если класс наследуется от определенного интерфейса C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть интерфейс `IWeapon`. Я хочу что бы все классы которые реализуют `IWeapon` добавлялись в выпадающий список. Я могу пополнить этот список одной строчкой кода, но в какую функцию ее написать чтобы после сохранения файла(пересборки всего проекта) выполнять эту строчку. Пересматривать все классы в проекте не вариант, так как классов будет становится все больше и это будет замедлять пересборку проекта.

Comment: `Type.IsAssignableFrom` по типам в сборке(ах)?

Comment: Обычно человеки делают БД предметов, если их много, ну или массивчик в `ScriptableObject`. Какую-нибудь каталогализацию.

Comment: Я ее и делаю в `ScriptableObject`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно создавать 200 классов если у вас будет 200 видов оружия. Класс нужно создавать только на тип вооружения, например стрелковое, гранаты и т.д. Всё остальное должно регулироваться параметрами из данных, а не быть захардкожено. То есть чтобы добавить новый пистолет в игру, нужно создать для него файл с данными, а не переписывать код и не пересобирать проект. Избавляйтесь от хардкода. По формату для хранилища попробуйте сериализацию в JSON. Для Unity есть мощная библиотека JSON.NET, которая умеет сериализовать в том числе типы объектов (Type Name Handling). То есть все свои `IWeapon[]` можно записать в файл одной строчкой кода, и так же одной строчкой кода прочитать.

Следовательно и получать список классов не придется, ну если вы конечно не захотите создать редактор пушек, где придется для создания новой пушки цеплять исполняющий ее скрипт.

Грубо говоря, у вас не должно быть разных классов, где код одинаковый, а отличаются только данные.

А игроку надо локализованные названия показывать, а не внутренние названия классов.

А что касается вопроса, то можно использовать рефлексию.

```
Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
foreach (Type type in types.Where(t => typeof(IWeapon).IsAssignableFrom(t))
{
    Debug.Log(type.Name);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Странно, почему то он находит только оригинал интерфейса, а реализаторов не находит.

Comment: `typeof(IWeapon).IsAssignableFrom(types[i])` такой код мне подошел

Comment: @ZZZ поправил ответ, постоянно путаю с `IsAssignableTo`. :)